# how to uninstall refinery plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms, portfolio

I have been working with refinery cms for a website and was trying to create a gallery with the portfolio plugin. I decided another plugin would work better but now I am stuck with the databases and a portfolio page on my menu that I cannot delete. What is the best way to uninstall a plugin? Here are the commands I have tried:

`rm -rf vendor/plugins/refinerycms_portfolio`

`bundle exec gem uninstall refinerycms-portfolio`

They seem to have uninstalled some things but the portfolio tab is still on the menu and throws an error when I click it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All good now, it seems all I had to do was rollback the database, delete the migration and the plugin was fully removed.